# newbie: get attribute value of an object gives error undefined method for #<ActiveRecord::Relation>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, object, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Im trying to figure out how i would get attributes/propertys from an object.

locations.rb model would have attribute :city

```
    @location = Location.where(:id => 1)
```

Seems to go find inside my controller but how would I get access to the :city from that @location ?

I tried all combinations and thought it had to be:

- @location.city
- puts @location.city needs to print value of city

But instead I'm getting

```
undefined method `city' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007ff2d1506330>
```

Anyone could clarify why this not work and what I miss here? Ive searched for examples on how to do this and tried all combinations to no avail :(
thx

Comment: Try <%= @location.inspect %> in your view to see all the attributes of your instance variable, maybe that will help.

Comment: thx, that gives out all the attributes just like in console  city is in there and its filled. but still unsure on how to get access to it. thx

Comment: If you do `@location.inspect`, you should notice that the `Location` object is actually wrapped in square brackets (an array) - it would look like `[#<Location ...>]` as opposed to just `#<Location ...>`.  If you notice that in the future, it can help you figure out if you're dealing with an individual object or a collection of them.

Comment: Good one BaronVonBraun thx for pointing out

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arel's `where` query returns a collection of models, even if there is only one result.

`Location.where(:id => 1)` will effectively return an array (actually an `ActiveRecord::Relation`) of `Location` objects, even though there will only be one result from this particular query in that array.

To get around this, either do

```
@location = Location.where(:id => 1).first
# or...
@location = Location.find(1)  # Finds by ID
```

Comment: I thought it must have been something simple, thx for the clarification. This was frustratingly not clear to me. thx for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve an object from its id, use

```
@location = Location.find(1)  # 1 is the id your looking for
```

Read the guide on [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) to find more about `find` and `where`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `where` returns an array not an instance but `find` does. As `city` is the attribute your model has instance method `city` which you cant use for array. So try `@location = Location.find(1)` then `@location.city`